# second jquery $(function(){...}) is not being loaded if there are two

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, inheritance

I have base.html which has all general code that will be inherited by other templates.

and i have profile.html which inherits many things from base.html

In base.html I have this:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
    alert('base');
 })
</script>
```

and this will be inherited by all templates.

and in profile.html, next to inherited code, I have this also:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
    alert('profile');
 })
</script>
```

once I load the profile page, I am getting only `base`and not `profile` output. why is the second `$(function(){...})` not being loaded?

I load jquery source in base.html.

Comment: This should work fine. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @BenM, no, i dont see any errors in console, it is really weird.. i thought, i am not loading jquery source, but i am..

Comment: Do you have an online demo we can see?

Comment: @BenM, look, i am getting this error in console. ``Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker' `` and this is before inheritance placeholder, so i think, it is blocking the second code to load?

Comment: Could you please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Also, I have never heard about inheritance in HTML. Is this some templating engine you are using? If yes, providing its name would be helpful too.

Comment: @BenM, it is working now, that error was the reason.

Comment: Thought so ;) Glad you got it sorted!